# Scrollable PrimeNG table breaks body width when all expandable rows are collapsed

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

:-)

I use 2 features of the PrimeNG table (`<p-table>`, Version 8) in combination:

- [Scroll](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll)
- [Row expansion](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion)

This works quite well as long as the table is indeed scrollable:
[image]

But when to many rows are collapsed the table is smaller than the threashold `scrollHeight` I configured at the `p-table`. That makes the scrollbar go away so that the table body fills up that space - without the header getting wider too:
[image]

#### What I tried so far

- Force the scrollbar: According to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/) giving an html element the css style `overflow-y: scroll` enforces the scrollbar to allways be visible. However the scrollable element I deal with here is generated by PrimeNG and so far I couldn't overwrite it's style
- Use `position: sticky` to make the header follow: I already blowed hours in applying that attribute to the header. It never took effect. Thats why I tried this with the `scrollable` function of `p-table`in the first place.

May the force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works for me with vertical scrollbar always be shown:

```
body .ui-table-scrollable-body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```